# Fourier Coefficient for an equation with Exponential and Trigonmetric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to find the Fourier coefficients ($G_{pq}$) of the following equation

$$
\alpha e^{-\beta y} = \sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\ G_{pq} \cos(px)[\frac{\cos(qy) + \sin(qy) - e^{-\beta y}}{q^2}] - \sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty G_{pq}\cos(px)\cos(qy)
$$

How to particularly handle the exponential term ? 
Is there some sort of expansion I need to consider ?